# Top N accuracy for an imbalanced multiclass classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, classification, class-imbalance, accuracy

I have a multi-class classification problem that is imbalanced. The task is about animal classification.

Since it's imbalanced, I am using macro-F1 metric and the current result that I have is: `51.59`.

The issue that I am facing is that, this task will be considered as a recommending task, where the accuracy of TOP-N is needed. When I compute the TOP-N accuracy, I get the following: `Top-1: 88.58   Top-2: 94.86   Top-3: 96.48`.

As you can see, the accuracy for the TOP-N is totally biased to the majority class, where the gap between the macro-F1 and top-1 is big.

My question is, how can I consider the class imbalance when I calculate the Top-N accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your minority class is being poorly predicted and affecting your macro f1 score (see [this answer for more info](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/40900/whats-the-difference-between-sklearn-f1-score-micro-and-weighted-for-a-mult)

From the [sklearns top k accuracy score documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.top_k_accuracy_score.html) you can pass a list of weights to 'rebalance' the score.

> **sample_weight, array-like of shape (n_samples,), default=None**
> Sample weights. If None, all samples are given the same weight.